# Graphviz hierarchically display tree of subgraphs

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a program that autogenerates a graphviz .dot file, the contents of which are a tree of subgraphs. When I observe how this file is rendered, the tree seems to be 'flattened', poorly displaying the hierarchical structure. I would like to know how to correct this issue, and properly render this tree.

In the past, I have used the fdp layout program to render this graph. It was able to show the hierarchical structure of the tree, but the contents of the nodes, which are subgraphs, were not very readable. I want to use the dot layout program since it does a better job layering the nodes of the subgraphs, and is said to be ideal for hierarchical graphs.

Please see the image below for a sample graph that shows the poorly rendered tree.

[image]

The code that generates this figure is:

```
digraph G {
compound=true
subgraph cluster_649 {label = EPISODE649count3
subgraph cluster_STATE650 {
label = State_1;
EPISODE649HEIGHT643[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649LEN642[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649Y641[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649X640[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649BLOCK639[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649HEIGHT638[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649LEN637[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649Y636[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649X635[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649TRIANGLE634[label="TRIANGLE",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649ON645[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649ON555[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649CLEAR647[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649CLEAR557[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649CLEAR558[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649ON556[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649BLOCK545[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649X546[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649Y547[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649LEN548[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649HEIGHT549[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649BLOCK550[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649X551[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649Y552[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649LEN553[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649HEIGHT554[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE649BLOCK639 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT643;
EPISODE649BLOCK639 -> EPISODE649LEN642;
EPISODE649BLOCK639 -> EPISODE649Y641;
EPISODE649BLOCK639 -> EPISODE649X640;
EPISODE649TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT638;
EPISODE649TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE649LEN637;
EPISODE649TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE649Y636;
EPISODE649TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE649X635;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT643;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649LEN642;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649Y641;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649X640;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649BLOCK639;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT638;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649LEN637;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649Y636;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649X635;
EPISODE649ON645 -> EPISODE649TRIANGLE634;
EPISODE649ON555 -> EPISODE649ON645;
EPISODE649ON555 -> EPISODE649ON556;
EPISODE649CLEAR647 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT638;
EPISODE649CLEAR647 -> EPISODE649LEN637;
EPISODE649CLEAR647 -> EPISODE649Y636;
EPISODE649CLEAR647 -> EPISODE649X635;
EPISODE649CLEAR647 -> EPISODE649TRIANGLE634;
EPISODE649CLEAR557 -> EPISODE649CLEAR647;
EPISODE649CLEAR557 -> EPISODE649CLEAR558;
EPISODE649CLEAR558 -> EPISODE649BLOCK545;
EPISODE649CLEAR558 -> EPISODE649X546;
EPISODE649CLEAR558 -> EPISODE649Y547;
EPISODE649CLEAR558 -> EPISODE649LEN548;
EPISODE649CLEAR558 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT549;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649BLOCK545;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649X546;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649Y547;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649LEN548;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT549;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649BLOCK550;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649X551;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649Y552;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649LEN553;
EPISODE649ON556 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT554;
EPISODE649BLOCK545 -> EPISODE649X546;
EPISODE649BLOCK545 -> EPISODE649Y547;
EPISODE649BLOCK545 -> EPISODE649LEN548;
EPISODE649BLOCK545 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT549;
EPISODE649BLOCK550 -> EPISODE649X551;
EPISODE649BLOCK550 -> EPISODE649Y552;
EPISODE649BLOCK550 -> EPISODE649LEN553;
EPISODE649BLOCK550 -> EPISODE649HEIGHT554;
}
649[shape=point style=invis]
}
subgraph cluster_559 {label = EPISODE559count1
subgraph cluster_STATE651 {
label = State_1;
EPISODE559CLEAR557[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559CLEAR558[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559ON555[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559ON556[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559BLOCK545[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559X546[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559Y547[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559LEN548[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559HEIGHT549[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559BLOCK550[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559X551[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559Y552[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559LEN553[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559HEIGHT554[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE559CLEAR557 -> EPISODE559CLEAR558;
EPISODE559CLEAR558 -> EPISODE559BLOCK545;
EPISODE559CLEAR558 -> EPISODE559X546;
EPISODE559CLEAR558 -> EPISODE559Y547;
EPISODE559CLEAR558 -> EPISODE559LEN548;
EPISODE559CLEAR558 -> EPISODE559HEIGHT549;
EPISODE559ON555 -> EPISODE559ON556;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559BLOCK545;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559X546;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559Y547;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559LEN548;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559HEIGHT549;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559BLOCK550;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559X551;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559Y552;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559LEN553;
EPISODE559ON556 -> EPISODE559HEIGHT554;
EPISODE559BLOCK545 -> EPISODE559X546;
EPISODE559BLOCK545 -> EPISODE559Y547;
EPISODE559BLOCK545 -> EPISODE559LEN548;
EPISODE559BLOCK545 -> EPISODE559HEIGHT549;
EPISODE559BLOCK550 -> EPISODE559X551;
EPISODE559BLOCK550 -> EPISODE559Y552;
EPISODE559BLOCK550 -> EPISODE559LEN553;
EPISODE559BLOCK550 -> EPISODE559HEIGHT554;
}
559[shape=point style=invis]
}
649 -> 559 [ltail=cluster_649 lhead=cluster_559];
subgraph cluster_625 {label = EPISODE625count1
subgraph cluster_STATE652 {
label = State_1;
EPISODE625CLEAR623[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625CLEAR624[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625ON621[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625ON622[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625BLOCK611[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625X612[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625Y613[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625LEN614[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625HEIGHT615[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625BLOCK616[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625X617[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625Y618[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625LEN619[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625HEIGHT620[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE625CLEAR623 -> EPISODE625CLEAR624;
EPISODE625CLEAR624 -> EPISODE625BLOCK611;
EPISODE625CLEAR624 -> EPISODE625X612;
EPISODE625CLEAR624 -> EPISODE625Y613;
EPISODE625CLEAR624 -> EPISODE625LEN614;
EPISODE625CLEAR624 -> EPISODE625HEIGHT615;
EPISODE625ON621 -> EPISODE625ON622;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625BLOCK611;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625X612;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625Y613;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625LEN614;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625HEIGHT615;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625BLOCK616;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625X617;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625Y618;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625LEN619;
EPISODE625ON622 -> EPISODE625HEIGHT620;
EPISODE625BLOCK611 -> EPISODE625X612;
EPISODE625BLOCK611 -> EPISODE625Y613;
EPISODE625BLOCK611 -> EPISODE625LEN614;
EPISODE625BLOCK611 -> EPISODE625HEIGHT615;
EPISODE625BLOCK616 -> EPISODE625X617;
EPISODE625BLOCK616 -> EPISODE625Y618;
EPISODE625BLOCK616 -> EPISODE625LEN619;
EPISODE625BLOCK616 -> EPISODE625HEIGHT620;
}
625[shape=point style=invis]
}
649 -> 625 [ltail=cluster_649 lhead=cluster_625];
subgraph cluster_648 {label = EPISODE648count1
subgraph cluster_STATE653 {
label = State_1;
EPISODE648CLEAR646[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648CLEAR647[label="CLEAR",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648ON644[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648ON645[label="ON",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648TRIANGLE634[label="TRIANGLE",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648X635[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648Y636[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648LEN637[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648HEIGHT638[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648BLOCK639[label="BLOCK",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648X640[label="X",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648Y641[label="Y",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648LEN642[label="LEN",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648HEIGHT643[label="HEIGHT",shape=oval,color=blue];
EPISODE648CLEAR646 -> EPISODE648CLEAR647;
EPISODE648CLEAR647 -> EPISODE648TRIANGLE634;
EPISODE648CLEAR647 -> EPISODE648X635;
EPISODE648CLEAR647 -> EPISODE648Y636;
EPISODE648CLEAR647 -> EPISODE648LEN637;
EPISODE648CLEAR647 -> EPISODE648HEIGHT638;
EPISODE648ON644 -> EPISODE648ON645;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648TRIANGLE634;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648X635;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648Y636;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648LEN637;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648HEIGHT638;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648BLOCK639;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648X640;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648Y641;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648LEN642;
EPISODE648ON645 -> EPISODE648HEIGHT643;
EPISODE648TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE648X635;
EPISODE648TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE648Y636;
EPISODE648TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE648LEN637;
EPISODE648TRIANGLE634 -> EPISODE648HEIGHT638;
EPISODE648BLOCK639 -> EPISODE648X640;
EPISODE648BLOCK639 -> EPISODE648Y641;
EPISODE648BLOCK639 -> EPISODE648LEN642;
EPISODE648BLOCK639 -> EPISODE648HEIGHT643;
}
648[shape=point style=invis]
}
649 -> 648 [ltail=cluster_649 lhead=cluster_648];
}
```

Observe that in order to draw edges from cluster to cluster, I've created invisible nodes in each cluster, like: `625[shape=point style=invis]` and connected two invisible nodes if there is a parent/child relation between the two clusters, like: `649 -> 625 [ltail=cluster_649 lhead=cluster_625];`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your invisible nodes were a good idea, but you got caught by **dot**'s (unwritten?) rule that all nodes should be on the same rank unless there is a command the "forces" a new rank.  If you change "**invisible**" to "**dotted**", you will see what happened to those nodes.
I tried to find a straightforward way to get **dot** to play nicely with those extra nodes, but failed.
Eventually I used some of the existing nodes to accomplish what I assume is the goal.
I left these edges visible so you could easily see what I changed.
I also added peripheries and margin attributes.
A cut-down version of the program:

```
digraph G {
  compound = true 
  // a dummy cluster to pad the left side
  subgraph cluster_dummy{
      label="" ; peripheries=0;node[style=invis]; {rank=same _a; _b }
  }

  peripheries=0

  subgraph cluster_649 {
    label = EPISODE649count3 

    subgraph cluster_STATE650 {
    graph [ margin=30]
      label = State_1;
      // unmodified nodes go here
    }
  } 


  subgraph cluster_559 {
    label = EPISODE559count1 

    subgraph cluster_STATE651 {
    graph [ margin=30]
      label = State_1;
      // unmodified nodes go here
    } 
   }

  subgraph cluster_625 {

    label = EPISODE625count1 
    subgraph cluster_STATE652 {
      graph [ margin=30]
      label = State_1;
      // unmodified nodes go here
      } 
     }

  subgraph cluster_648 {

    label = EPISODE648count1
    subgraph cluster_STATE653 {
      graph [ margin=30]
      label = State_1;
      // unmodified nodes go here
      }
    }

  EPISODE649HEIGHT638 -> EPISODE559ON555  [weight=0 style=dotted]
  EPISODE649HEIGHT638 -> EPISODE625ON621  [weight=0 style=dotted]
  EPISODE649HEIGHT638 -> EPISODE648ON644  [weight=0 style=dotted]
}
```

[image]